# Building an custom 2-dimensional Lookup function in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project to built-in a custom lookup function in VBA Excel using the range, I have tried to execute the code in different ways but I still can't get the result yet.
[image]

The code that I have written is:

```
Function lookUp1(RowTable As Range, RowValue As String, ColTable As Range, ColValue As String) As Variant

Dim row As Variant
Dim col As Variant

For Each row In RowTable
    If row.Value = RowValue Then
        row.row
    End If
Next row

For Each col In ColTable
    If col = ColValue Then
        col.Column
   End If
Next col

lookUp1 = Cells(row, col)

End Function
```

in the worksheet screenshot that I have attached, the answer should be $20, and I keep receiving an error value

I will be so grateful for your help:)

Comment: `Dim r as Long, c as Long`, `r = row.Row`, `c =  c.Column`, `lookup1 = Cells(r, c)`... but instead of looping you could just use `Match`.

Comment: @BigBen c = Col.column

Comment: Yes, typo... really one should not loop here though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Row and col were returning empty on your function.

```
Function lookUp1(ByRef rowtable As Range, ByRef rowvalue As String, ByRef coltable As Range, ByRef colvalue As String) As Variant

Dim cel As Variant

Dim row As Variant
Dim col As Variant

For Each cel In rowtable
    If cel.Value = rowvalue Then
        row = cel.row
    End If
Next cel

For Each cel In coltable
    If cel = colvalue Then
        col = cel.Column
   End If
Next cel

lookUp1 = Cells(row, col).Value


End Function
```

Comment: try following the best practice suggested from the comments above :)